# 5 Million regex matches eats my CPU [Perl]

Tags: html, regex, performance, perl

I have an application that fires several processes. Each process loads an HTML file and tries to find whether a pattern appears in it, something like this:

```
OUTER:
while(my ($prov,$arr_ref) = each(%{$self->{TAGS}})) {
    foreach my $tag (@{$arr_ref}) {
        if ($html =~ m/\Q$tag\E/i) {
            $provider = $prov;
            last OUTER;
        }
    }
}
```

`$self->{TAGS}` key is a pattern name, and the value is a reference to array with strings (scalars).

I was profiling the program, and found that this part:

```
$html =~ m/\Q$tag\E/i
```

makes my CPU jump to 100%. If I remove it, it barely gets to 10%.

I have only one approach in mind, which is turning all the scalars (strings) inside each array ref to compiled regex (`qr/.../`). I guess it won't improve it so much, since I guess the issue in fact when the regex actually searches all the HTML pages, which can be hundreds of bytes in size.

What can I do to improve this section?

**SUB-QUESTION:** due to the answers below,and some testing I made, I will sharpen my question, the issue is NOT the regex, I already tried the `index` way before I asked this question, also tried compiled regex with `qr//`, this issue is, with the size of the html files, the `$html` contents are HTML text, sometimes its small, and sometimes its big, so the issue here is: WHAT IS THE BEST WAY (Resource wise...) TO FIND IF A STRING APPEARS INSIDE A LARGER (LETS SAY 1MB IN SIZE) STRING?

Thanks.

Comment: REGEX is rarely the answer in case of high iteration count or high traffic issues. You want to get rid of it, and try to use native Perl functions. (And this is coming from someone who has zero knowledge on Perl).

Comment: there is nothing non-native in my code... regex is part of Perl, the a core part of it. since I'm searching for patterns, I need to use regex's, unless you have another solution?

Comment: @Truth - Perl is essentially built on top of Regular Expressions.

Comment: It's always nice to make a fool of myself :D

Comment: Can you offload the loop to a series of individual calls or somehow otherwise break the searches up? Maybe process the pages in a dedicated script, save to a database, and then just search for matches? Something to avoid what you're doing now.

Comment: XY problem alert! Give more details: sample input, sample patterns. If you explain what you want to achieve, instead of asking how to treat a symptom, we should be able to come up with an algorithm that fares better.

Comment: Truth: regex is optimized for such cases, but using non-regex search can still be faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`index`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html) should increase performance since you'll get rid of all the overhead of using regular-expressions. Please, do a benchmark!

```perl
$html_searchable = lc ($html);

...    

while ( ... ) {
  foreach ( ... ) {
    if (index ($html_searchable, lc ($tag)) > -1) {
      ... # we got a match
    }
  }
}
```

If you'd like to increase it even more you should store all your `$tag`s as lowercase strings so that you don't have to [`lc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/lc.html) the same string multiple times.

**Documentation**

- [index - perldoc.perl.org](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html)
- [lc - perldoc.perl.org](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/lc.html)

Answer (score 4):

\Q means that your regex can be replaced with [index](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html). For case independent search, both $html and $tag should be converted to lower case, early as possible.

```
my $htmllc=lc($html);
while () {
  ...
  if (index($htmllc,$tag)>-1) {
   ...
  }
}
```

P.S. You should try benchmarking several solutions.